# how to restore a lost file on luks

Tags: luks

I have a file that has been overwritten.
It's a .odt and mixed up with another .odt file on same partition.
LUKS fully encrypted.

It is not the point to unlock the vulume an mount. But the file is corrupt, overwritter with other data.

Any clues? Regular programms won't take a LUKS drive.

Answer (score 0):

LUKS is an encryption layer between hard disk and the actual filesystem. You need to use `cryptsetup` to unlock the encryption layer, and then run filesystem rescue utility on the unlocked device.